# What is it called when the same melody is played by two different voices but not starting at the same time and on a different pitch?

Tags: theory, terminology

Complete the following sentence:

> The 1st violin ______ the 2nd violin at the start of the extract.

[image: Violin 1 and Violin 2 staves]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could say it's [**imitation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imitation_(music)):

> In music, imitation is the repetition of a melody in a polyphonic texture shortly after its first appearance in a different voice.

Wikipedia uses this example from Bartok's Mikrokosmos, which is similar to yours:

[image]

Also, this example from Bach's Fugue no. 16:

[image]

> The 1st violin **imitates** the 2nd violin at the start of the extract.

Answer (score 0):

"Imitates" is probably best, but another option would be **"follows"**.

> The initial melody is called the leader (or *dux*), while the imitative melody, which is played in a different voice, is called the follower (or *comes*).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_(music)